# How do I replace or override or fix the node error "missing script build" when deploying my application to Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, deployment, package.json

I'm trying to deploy my project to firebase through node.js which I just downloaded but I am getting an error.

It says npm ERR! missing script: build

I already checked my package.json file and there is no build reference inside of there. I tried putting one in and that didn't work either. I am at an impasse. :(
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Package.json file

```
 {
 "name": "functions",
 "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
 "scripts": {
"build:production": "node --8.9.1",
"serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
"shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
"start": "npm run shell",
"deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
"logs": "firebase functions:log"
 },
 "dependencies": {
"firebase-admin": "~5.4.2",
"firebase-functions": "^0.7.1"
 },
 "private": true
 }
```

Firebase.json

```
 {
 "functions": {
 "predeploy": "npm --prefix functions run build",
 "source": "functions"
 }
 }
```

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8193

Comment: when I change it to just "build" I still get the same error

Comment: What command are you using? 'npm run build'?